# Redux , state.concat is not a function at rootReducer. And being forced to reRender an element for it to see the state change

Tags: reactjs, redux

So I have this sidebar component where I load my store and my dispatcher

```
    //select
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return { renderedEl: state.renderedEl }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return{
        renderLayoutElement: element => dispatch(renderLayoutElement(element))
    }
}
```

Then inside the same component this Is how I trigger the dispatcher

```
renderEl = (el) => {
    var elementName = el.target.getAttribute('id');
    var renderedElements = this.props.renderedEl; //this is data from the  store

    for (let key in renderedElements) {
        if (key == elementName) {
            renderedElements[key] = true
        }
    }

    this.props.renderLayoutElement({renderedElements});


}
```

Then as I understand it gets sent to the reducer

```
import {RENDER_LAYOUT_ELEMENT} from "../constants/action-types"

const initialState = {
    renderedEl: {
        heimdall: false,
        skadi: false,
        mercator: false
    }
}

function rootReducer(state = initialState, action){

    if(action.type === RENDER_LAYOUT_ELEMENT){
        return Object.assign({},state,{
            renderedEl: state.renderedEl.concat(action.payload)
        })
    }

    return state 
}

export default rootReducer;
```

This is its action

```
import {RENDER_LAYOUT_ELEMENT} from "../constants/action-types"

export function renderLayoutElement(payload) {
    return { type: RENDER_LAYOUT_ELEMENT, payload }
  };
```

Now the thing is. Im receiving a

> state.renderedEl.concat is not a function at rootreducer / at dispatch

I dont understand why does that happen.

Becuase, actually the store gets updated as I can see, but the console returns that error. And I have to reload the render that uses the props of that store (with an onhover) in order to be able to see the changes. It doesnt happen automatically as it would happen with a state

Comment: `renderedEl` is an *object* by default, `({}).concat` is `undefined`.

Comment: @Vlad you just left a comment there and deleted it afterwards, but it worked

Comment: Sorry, I wanna give more details
Let's try this one:
        return { ...state, {
            renderedEl: { ...state.renderedEl, ...action.payload }
        }

Comment: @VladSerdyuk that one works too, but with one less curly brace ```return { ...state, renderedEl: { ...state.renderedEl, ...action.payload } }```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(action.type === RENDER_LAYOUT_ELEMENT){
        return { ...state, renderedEl: { ...state.renderedEl, ...action.payload } };
    }
```

Duplicate from comments maybe it can be helpful to someone else :)